# Bypass mibew messenger connection form by using my own session from my java web application

Tags: java, php

I have a Java web based application and I need to connect it to mibew messenger 2.0. I need this because I want to be logged in automatically when I log in into my Java web application.

So when I submit the data form (username and password), I need to retrieve these data forms (username, password and session) sent by my application into mibew messenger (http://localhost:9090/mibew/index.php/operator).

So in 2 words, when I am logged in my java web application:

- I send the username, password and the session to mibew messenger 2.0
- and the operator mibew web page (http://localhost:9090/mibew/index.php/operator) is opened or displayed.

Comment: You should improve your title with a clearer message and think that some of us use RSS reader so keep it simple and short.